# Django datetime TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str

Tags: django, typeerror

```
Internal Server Error: /api/orders/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):**strong t[enter image description here][1]ext**
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response      
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view     
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception        
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\backend\base\views\order_views.py", line 31, in addOrderItems
    order = Order.objects.create(
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method       
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 514, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 857, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1000, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1041, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method       
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1434, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1620, in execute_sql   
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1547, in as_sql        
    value_rows = [
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1548, in <listcomp>    
    [
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1549, in <listcomp>    
    self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj))
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1487, in prepare_value 
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 910, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1546, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1524, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1403, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1485, in to_python  
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\Users\kalya\OneDrive\Desktop\my app\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 114, in parse_datetime        
    return datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(value)
```

[image]

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser
from rest_framework.response import Response

from base.models import Product, Order, OrderItem, ShippingAddress
from base.serializers import ProductSerializer, OrderSerializer


from rest_framework import status


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def addOrderItems(request):

    user = request.user
    data = request.data

    orderItems = data['orderItems']

    if orderItems and len(orderItems) == 0:
        return Response({'detail': 'No Order Item'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    else:

        # Create order

        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=user,
            paymentMethod=data['paymentMethod'],
            taxPrice=data['taxPrice'],
            shippingPrice=data['shippingPrice'],
            totalPrice=data['totalPrice'],
        )
        # Create Shipping Address

        shipping = ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            order=order,
            address=data['ShippingAddress']['address'],
            city=data['ShippingAddress']['city'],
            postalCode=data['ShippingAddress']['postalCode'],
            country=data['ShippingAddress']['country'],

        )
        # Create Order items and set order to orderItem relationship
        for i in orderItems:
            product = Product.objects.get(_id=i['product'])

            item = OrderItem.objects.create(
                product=product,
                order=order,
                name=product.name,
                qty=i['qty'],
                price=i['price'],
                image=product.image.url,

            )
            # Update stock
            product.countInStock -= item.qty
            product.save()

        serializer = OrderSerializer(order, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getOrderById(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(_id=pk)
        if user.is_staff or user.user == user:
            serializer = OrderSerializer(order, many=False)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            Response({'details': 'Not authenticated to view this 
            order'},
                     status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except:
        Response({'details': 'Order doesnot exist'},
                 status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
import { useNavigate, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Button, Row, Col, ListGroup, Card, Image, } from 'react-bootstrap'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import Message  from '../components/Message'
import CheckoutSteps  from '../components/CheckoutSteps'
import { createOrder } from '../actions/orderActions'
import { ORDER_CREATE_RESET} from '../constants/orderConstants'

function PlaceOrderScreen() {
    
    const orderCreate = useSelector( state => state.orderCreate)
    const { order, error, success } = orderCreate

    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const cart = useSelector( state => state.cart)
    cart.itemsPrice = cart.cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0).toFixed(2)
    cart.shippingPrice = (cart.itemsprice > 0 ? 0 : 10).toFixed(2)
    cart.taxPrice = Number((0.13) * cart.itemsPrice).toFixed(2)
    cart.totalPrice =(Number(cart.itemsPrice) + Number(cart.shippingPrice) + Number(cart.taxPrice)).toFixed(2)



    useEffect(() =>{ 
        
        if(!cart.paymentMethod){
            navigate('/payment')
        }
        else {
            if(success)
            {
            navigate(`/order/${order._id}`)
            dispatch({type:ORDER_CREATE_RESET})
            }
        }   
    }, [navigate, success, cart, order, dispatch])

    const placeOrder = () =>{
        dispatch(createOrder(
            {
                orderItems: cart.cartItems,
                shippingAddress: cart.shippingAddress,
                paymentMethod: cart.paymentMethod,
                itemsPrice: cart.itemsPrice,
                shippingPrice: cart.shippingPrice,
                taxPrice: cart.taxPrice,
                totalPrice: cart.totalPrice, 

            }
        ))
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 step4 />
        <Row>
            <Col md={8}>
                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Shipping</h2>

                        <p>
                            <strong>Shipping: </strong>
                            {cart.shippingAddress.address},  {cart.shippingAddress.city}
                            {'  '}
                            {cart.shippingAddress.postalCode},
                            {'  '}
                            {cart.shippingAddress.country}
                        </p>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Payment</h2>

                        <p>
                            <strong>Method: </strong>
                            {cart.paymentMethod}
                        </p>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Order Items</h2>

                        <p>
                            <strong>Shipping: </strong>
                         </p>
                            {cart.cartItems.length === 0 ? <Message variant={'info'}>
                                Your cart is empty
                            </Message> : (
                                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                                    {cart.cartItems.map((item , index) => (
                                        <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col md={1}>
                                                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid  rounded />
                                                </Col>
                                                <Col>
                                                 <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                                                </Col>

                                                <Col md={4}>
                                                    {item.qty} X ${item.price} =${(item.qty * item.price).toFixed(2)}
                                                </Col>
                                            </Row>
                                        </ListGroup.Item>
                                    ))}
                                </ListGroup>
                            )}
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
            </Col>

            <Col md={4}>
                <Card>
                    <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                        <ListGroup.Item>    
                            <h2>Order Summary</h2>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>    
                            <Row>
                                <Col>Items: </Col>
                                <Col>${cart.itemsPrice}</Col>
                            </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                        <ListGroup.Item>    
                            <Row>
                                <Col>Shipping:</Col>
                                <Col>${cart.shippingPrice}</Col>
                            </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>    
                            <Row>
                                <Col>Tax: </Col>
                                <Col>${cart.taxPrice}</Col>
                            </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>    
                            <Row>
                                <Col>Total Price: </Col>
                                <Col>${cart.totalPrice}</Col>
                            </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
                        </ListGroup.Item>


                        <ListGroup.Item>    
                            <Button
                                type='button'
                                className='btn-block'
                                disabled={cart.cartItems === 0}
                                onClick={placeOrder}
                            >
                                Place Order
                            </Button>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                    </ListGroup>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PlaceOrderScreen
```

```
from pyexpat import model
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

from .models import Product, Order, OrderItem, ShippingAddress


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    _id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin']

    def get__id(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff

    def get_name(self, obj):
        name = obj.first_name
        if name == '':
            name = obj.email

        return name


class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin', 'token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'


class ShippingAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShippingAddress
        fields = '__all__'


class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = '__all__'


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderItems = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    ShippingAddress = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_orderItems(self, obj):
        items = obj.orderitem_set.all()
        serializer = OrderItemSerializer(items, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    def get_shippingAddress(self, obj):
        try:
            address = ShippingAddressSerializer(
                obj.shippingaddress, many=False).data
        except:
            address = False
        return address

    def get_user(self, obj):
        user = obj.user
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=False)
        return serializer.data
```

Answer (score 4):

first of all you need to delete the files inside migrations  folder and and __ pycache __ foledr and  you may need clear the database
after that run
`python manage.py makemigrations`
it will show you those lines on the terminal
'''
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'created_at' to customuser without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
   '''
   type 1
   should ask you
   '''
   Please enter the default value as valid Python.
   The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so it is possible to provide e.g. timezone.now as a value.
   Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
   '''
   type`timezone.now`

and run
`python manage.py migrate`
will work perfectly

Comment: I had same problem and this was exactly what work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can't use str() directly for the time module

use this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.createdAt
```

or use:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.createdAt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}"
```

[data formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)

Comment: My problem is not solved i got same error. i have post my code also

Comment: why do you want to stringify your date field?

Comment: Sorry Bt i am learning from the video. In the video he told to stringify date so i am doing the same. Please Can you tell me why error has occured and where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue, I fixed it by going back to a older saved file and trying it again.

I added this to my models

```
    class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

If that doesn't work I read somewhere that says you have to have python version 3.9 or below for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to apply

def **str**(self):
return self.createdAt

to your model.py before making a migrations, after the migrations
list option woulld be prompt out

1. Provide a one-off default now which will be set on all existing rows
2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
   Select an option: 1

Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
[default: timezone.now] >>> timezone.now

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. My first model was causing this same error because of variable **`date`** which seems to conflict with internal variable somewhere in django. So I changed this

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False, null=False)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=False)
    ## error caused due to field `date`
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

to variable other than `date` in which I changed to `published_date`.

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False, null=False)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=False)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error in my code

Here is my code having issues

```
last_check_in_dt = datetime.strptime((datetime.fromisoformat(AlertLastCheckIn).strftime(MessageConstantsSerializer.date_format)), MessageConstantsSerializer.date_format)
```

Error : `TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str`

To solve my problem i simply convert DateTime Field to str so python can understand it clearly

```
last_check_in_dt = datetime.strptime((datetime.fromisoformat(str(AlertLastCheckIn)).strftime(MessageConstantsSerializer.date_format)), MessageConstantsSerializer.date_format)
```

By wrapping str around my variable solved it